# Is it natural and correct to say "it's in my desk" meaning that the things is in the drawer of my desk?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is it natural and correct to say *it's in my desk* meaning that the thing is in the drawer of my desk? For example:

> Person A: Can I borrow your phone charger?
>
> Person B: Sure, **it's in my desk.**

If doesn't sound good, what would you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(American English Answer)

Yes, you are correct. Any reasonable person would understand that when you say

> it's in my desk.

you mean specifically that the thing being referred to is inside a drawer/storage area of the desk.

Unless the thing is actually embedded into the desk itself. In which case, you would need to clarify to most people as this would be an unusual use of the term. Typically if Person A and B are referring to a container like a desk, it's common to say "it's in my x" and both A and B know that it means the thing is typically freely accessible and not embedded inside the container.

Further examples:

> Person A: Can I borrow your phone charger?
>
> Person B: Sure, it's in my vault.
>
> Person A: Can I borrow your golden doubloon?
>
> Person B: Sure, it's in my treasure chest.
>
> Person A: Can I borrow your Jackie Chan Movie collection ?
>
> Person B: Sure, it's in my room.
>
> Person A: Can I borrow your bottle of Domaine Leroy Musigny Grand Cru?
>
> Person B: Sure, it's in my cellar.
>
> Person A: Can I borrow your sugar
>
> Person B: Sure, it's in my cabinet.